# head don't appear with 3 figures (subfloat) in appendices

Tags: header-footer, subfloats

I make some appendices to my thesis. But I have some problems with head. There are 3 figures and each one occupies one page (all page). In first page appears everything normal. In second page too, but in third page don't appear the head. 
What's it wrong ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{  {fig/} }
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand\chaptername{Anexo}
\addto\captionsportuguese{%
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Anexo}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Anexos}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \leftmark}


\begin{document}

\appendixpage
\begin{appendices}



\chapter{Imagens SEM}

Imagens SEM de carbonato de cálcio natural, original e modificado, com uma resolução de 7500x e 20000x.

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
  \subfloat[H60-7500x]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{H60_7500X}}\hfill
  \subfloat[H60 Modificado - 7500x]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{H60-M2_7500X}}\\
  \subfloat[H60-20000x]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{H60_20000X}}\hfill
  \subfloat[H60 Modificado - 20000x]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{H60-M2_20000x-_2}}\\
  \caption{This is lot of figures arranged side by side in matrix form with captions for each and a main caption}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
  \subfloat[H90-7500x]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{H90_7500X_2}}\hfill
  \subfloat[H90 Modificado - 7500x]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{H90-M2_-_7500x_-_2}}\\
  \subfloat[H90-20000x]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{H90_2000X_2}}\hfill
  \subfloat[H90 Modificado - 20000x]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{H90-M2-20000x}}\\
  \caption{This is lot of figures arranged side by side in matrix form with captions for each and a main caption}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
  \subfloat[H60-7500x]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{H90_E7500X_2}}\hfill
  \subfloat[H60 Modificado - 7500x]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{H90E-M2_-_7500x}}\\
  \subfloat[H60-20000x]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{H90_E_20000X}}\hfill
  \subfloat[H60 Modificado - 20000x]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{H90E-M2_-_20000x-2}}\\
  \caption{This is lot of figures arranged side by side in matrix form with captions for each and a main caption}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the right hand pages, the header shows the section name, which is empty.

You can change the behavior inside the `appendices` environment with

```
\appendixpage
\begin{appendices}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \leftmark}
```